# In Tkinter how can I correct this loop/function so that each button changes a value to the value of the button?

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

In Tkinter how can I correct this loop/function so that each button changes a value to the value of the button?

This is a simplified version of my code, at the moment each button changes the value of size to 15 rather than the number on the button. I was wondering if there was anyway of fixing this loop without printing each individual button and value without a loop?

```
from Tkinter import *

size = 7

def AI():
    AIBoard = Tk()        
    AIBoard.title("Board Select")
    BoardSize = Label(AIBoard, text = "Please pick a board size: ", font = ('Helvetica',20))
    BoardSize.pack(side = 'top')

    for a in range(5,16,1):
        sizeBut = Button(AIBoard, text = a, width = 5, command = lambda: inputBoardSize(a))
        sizeBut.pack(side = 'left')

    AIBoard.mainloop()

def inputBoardSize(x):
    size = x
    print size

AI()
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your lambda to bind the value at the time the anonymous function is created.

```
lambda a=a: inputBoardSize(a)
```